# Why is my query counting an open for a send

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  sl.randomAB,
  sl.JobID,
  COUNT(DISTINCT sl.SubscriberKey) AS TotalSent,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.SubscriberKey) AS TotalOpened, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey) AS TotalClicked
FROM SendLog sl
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON sl.JobID = o.JobID AND sl.ListID = o.ListID AND sl.BatchID = o.BatchID AND sl.SubID = o.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON sl.JobID = c.JobID AND sl.ListID = c.ListID AND sl.BatchID = c.BatchID AND sl.SubID = c.SubscriberID
WHERE 
  sl.randomAB IN ('1', '2') 
GROUP BY 
  sl.randomAB, 
  sl.JobID
```

The randomAB field is a custom field that I added to the sendlog. It containts the value 1 or 2. The first time I do a test send and do noting everything looks fine. But the moment I open an email it adds it to the TotalSent. So when sending 2 emails and open both then the TotalSent end up in 4. How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding isUnique = true at the end of your joins and see if it helps?

```
SELECT 
  sl.randomAB,
  sl.JobID,
  COUNT(DISTINCT sl.SubscriberKey) AS TotalSent,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.SubscriberKey) AS TotalOpened, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.SubscriberKey) AS TotalClicked
FROM SendLog sl
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON sl.JobID = o.JobID AND sl.ListID = o.ListID AND sl.BatchID = o.BatchID AND sl.SubID = o.SubscriberID AND o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON sl.JobID = c.JobID AND sl.ListID = c.ListID AND sl.BatchID = c.BatchID AND sl.SubID = c.SubscriberID AND c.IsUnique = 1
WHERE 
  sl.randomAB IN ('1', '2') 
GROUP BY 
  sl.randomAB, 
  sl.JobID
```

Comment: Ah yes. That did the trick.